# Ist dieser Satz richtig geschrieben?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

Guten Tag,
Ich brauche einen Rat. Kann ich diesen Satz so schreiben?

> Als erstes möchte ich die kurze Definition der Integration in die Schulen erklären. Dann den ehemaligen und gegenwärtigen Zustand der Ausbildung vergleichen.

Comment: Please edit your question and add information, what exactly you are uncertain of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sofern "die Definition" nicht zuvor schon vorgestellt worden ist, dann ist "erklären" nicht das passende Wort, sondern eben "vorstellen". Und da "die Definition" eben noch nicht vorgestellt worden ist, muss es "eine kurze Definition" oder "meine kurze Definition" heißen.

"Integration in die Schulen" klingt nicht richtig oder nicht vollständig. Was wird "in die Schulen" integriert? Normalerweise findet Integration von etwas in (Dativ, nicht Akkusativ) etwas statt, also "in den Schulen", wobei das "von"-Objekt weit wichtiger ist und deswegen niemals weggelassen wird, während auf das "in"-Objekt meist verzichtet wird, weil es aus dem Kontext hervorgeht.

Ein "ehemaliger" Zustand setzt voraus, dass der Kontext den gegenwärtigen/aktuellen Zustand schon eingeführt hat. Da das hier noch nicht geschehen ist, würde ich eher vom historischen Zustand reden. Aber das ist hochsensibel abhängig vom Inhalt - kann also auch unpassend sein.

Und zuletzt die Zeichensetzung: da beide Sätze dasselbe Subjekt haben, handelt es sich streng genommen um einen Satz. Daher kein Punkt dazwischen, sondern ein Komma oder ein Semikolon.

Das alles zusammen genommen ergibt:

> Als erstes möchte ich eine kurze Definition der Integration von ??? (in den Schulen) vorstellen, dann den historischen und gegenwärtigen Zustand der Ausbildung vergleichen.